# How do i map dynamic tables with diffrent schema names

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have table with Names such as

> JS Engineering Services$Web User Setup Header **and** 
>   Sachin Sales & Service Pvt Ltd$Web User Setup Header

how do i map these tables with Ado.net Entity framework POCO Code first approach ? The table structures are the same . I have done POCO with Single Table names and Schema as Dbo just declaring table like

Web User Setup.

Also alongwith it I would like to ask That how to Create tables like Names with spaces. Something like above as i have mentioned . If we want to Create Table names with Spaces How to do it dynamically to generate a table name as

> Sachin Sales & Service Pvt Ltd$Web User Setup Header

using Ado.net Entity framework in Codefirst approach ?

Previously i used Nhibernate so shifted recently to Ado.net Entity framework . Liked the Fluent configuration in Ado.net Codefirst approach . Can someone guide me with the above mentioned scenario how to approach it ? Any dummy properties would be welcome . It doesnt matter . I jsut want to generate the table names dynamically Based on the fact the both scemas contain exactly same columns

Comment: Why do you want those tables to be generated? You mentioned that you already have these tables?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes, I already have those tables but I want to map them using Entity Framework. Actually they are navision tables . So i Want to use Entity framework behind the scenes to retrive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there are two things to address here seems:

**The table naming**, have you tried the following...
(from your `: DbContext` implementation class, method `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JSEngineeringServicesWebUser>()
    .ToTable("JS Engineering Services$Web User");
```

(note: you may need to experiment with this, I haven't worked w/ such names and don't have it handy to test, try fast)

another options is using `[Table("JS Engineering Services$Web User")]` as an attribute on your entity class. (note: I personally prefer the fluid methods as it give you more control (for other things, keys, relationships) and it's not often working well when 'mixing' the two)

...or take a look at this, similar question [Can I change the default schema name in entity framework 4.3 code-first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562883/can-i-change-the-default-schema-name-in-entity-framework-4-3-code-first)

**And 2nd problem is the fact the tables may be 'temp tables'**. That's a bit tricky to achieve. But if you have them in the Db (just look and work as temp tables) then you can go ahead and just map like any other entity.

If you need to create and tear-down dynamically - then consider this post here, with something similar...

[Cache table with Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020330/cache-table-with-entity-framework-4/10020565#10020565)

**EDIT:** from comments below, to update...

If the 'temp' tables are always the same like you say it is -

Then you should be ok with what's in [Cache table with Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020330/cache-table-with-entity-framework-4/10020565#10020565) - create a model to match the table model, or even you might need to create one table like that (to always be there, I'm not sure if code-first might complain if nothing to match at start, or to run with 'use the existing db' w/o checking), and use 'straight' SQL to run a query (from context class, like explained in the link) - and then list the output to that model class. And it might just work:)

Comment: Yes i can do that. It satisfies my query quite a lot . But what if on dynamic basis a new schema is added ? but "web user" footprint  remains the same . I can do that static way . Cause the `JS Engeneering Services` is a company name and is not controlled by application. Its controlled by navision . Whenever a new Company is added a New schema gets added and the table name would be then `Sachin Sales & Pvt LTD$Web User`

Comment: are the tables structured always the same? and just names change? problem is EF isn't great with temp tables and similar. You'd have to work around, look at the 'Cache table with Entity Framework 4' link above. You can execute and fetch custom SQL and that's in that case your best bet. If you can somehow match your 'dynamic tables' to always match some predefined model (no matter the name of the table, I mean fields/properties to match in type pretty much), then you could execute custom SQL, adjust naming in there - and on the exit pump that into a 'list' of a known model class.

Comment: i.e. there's no perfect solution here - you might even need to mix the EF/code-first with the custom SQL queries/fetching. In short, I'd suggest you find some common denominator here, and minimal requirements, scale down what you need to a min and try to work that out.

Comment: Yes the structure always remains the same just the Schema name  changes . The table model remains the same . But just schema name is diffrent.

Comment: Then you should be ok with what's in that link ('Cache table...') - create a model to match the table model, or even you might need to create one table like that (to always be there, I'm not sure if code-first might complain if nothing to match at start, or to run with 'use the existing db' w/o checking), and use 'straight' SQL to run a query (from context class, like explained in the link) - and then match the output to that model class. And it might just work:)

Comment: I guess your cache table link is for the time being is my best bet . But apparently thats kinda hack . I would stick to it until i find a new solution :)